# Mobile Pen-Testing approach for chatbox functionality

Tags: penetration-testing, penetration-tools, advanced-threat-protection

As a newbie mobile penetration tester, what is a more practical, step-by-step procedure to take on exploiting the chat functionality of a FinTech mobile app or how to discover vulnerabilities in the chat functions?

Because you are testing for loopholes, what are the best ways you can upload code to the chat functions without content filtering? You are free and permitted to carry out an in-depth access because you have signed an NDA and are employed by the company in question.

#PenetrationTesting